# I want speed up curl auto followers facebook

Tags: php, curl, facebook-graph-api

I have a curl call for facebook auto followers but this slowed down. Please help me boost speed for curl Request:

```
while($gettoken = mysql_fetch_assoc($laytoken)){
    auto('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$_POST['idfb'].'/subscribers?access_token='.$gettoken['token'].'&method=post');
}

header('Location: dash.php?i=4');

function auto($url){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $ch = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $ch;
}
```

Comment: You are at the mercy of how quickly the Other Server responds. So there is little you can do to speed up a curl from your end

Comment: You might look at [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) but that is a little complex to manage and may end up getting your IP banned by the other server for issuing too many requests to fast if you are not careful

Comment: what exactly does that script do? because /user/subscribers got removed with v2.0 of the graph api...